# How is modprobe run before mounting root? (no initrd)

Tags: linux, mount, boot, modprobe

I am booting linux mint(version 4.14.13+) without using `initrd`/`initramfs`, and I see that `/sbin/modprobe` is run before mounting the root file system. I was wondering how that is possible. I instrumented the kernel to `printk` whenever file system is used and that's how I know that `/sbin/modprobe` was used.

The following link contains the full `dmesg` output of my boot: [dmesg output](https://gist.github.com/rishikeshdevsot/7efd3f9a3536de300de65175e7432dc1)

---

```
[    3.175001] Used file system /sbin/modprobe!

[    3.179080] Used file system /dev/console!

[    3.844276] Used file system /dev/md0!

[    3.899302] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 8:17.
[    3.951578] devtmpfs: mounted

[    3.987527] Used file system /bin/sh!
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is successfully running `/sbin/modprobe`. But there is something that interested me here. It looks like it tries to open `/dev/console` before "devtmpfs: mounted" or "Mounted root (ext4 filesystem)", and there is no other attempt to open `/dev/console`. But I thought the kernel had to open `/dev/console` from some filesystem for init (/bin/sh in your case)...

It looks like if you do not have an initramfs, the kernel creates a very simple fake one.  If I'm following correctly, this is why it can open `/dev/console` before it has mounted a real root filesystem.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.14/init/noinitramfs.c

```
/*
 * Create a simple rootfs that is similar to the default initramfs
 */
static int __init default_rootfs(void)
{
    int err;

    err = sys_mkdir((const char __user __force *) "/dev", 0755);
    if (err < 0)
        goto out;

    err = sys_mknod((const char __user __force *) "/dev/console",
            S_IFCHR | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR,
            new_encode_dev(MKDEV(5, 1)));
    if (err < 0)
        goto out;

    err = sys_mkdir((const char __user __force *) "/root", 0700);
    if (err < 0)
        goto out;

    return 0;
```

The `/root` directory is relied on elsewhere in the kernel code, to mount and transition into the real `root=` filesystem.

The commit that introduces this function clarifies that this specific function is only used when both initrd and initramfs support are compiled out.  So otherwise, the "default initramfs" would provide the `/dev/console` and `/root`, if you did not pass a specific initramfs when booting the kernel, and you did not specify an initramfs to be built-in to the kernel.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/c33df4eaaf41fd3e34837a6ae9a5f9970c393d9f